# Decoding this GIS blob

Tags: geocoding, .net, python-3, binary, well-known-binary

I am new to the decoding world (and even to the world of gis), but I am definitely not new to programming and large data.  I was tasked with uncovering a column in our db with this information. It's probably some sort of geolocation w/ attributes... can anybody help?

The application is based in .net and the way we get this file (which i think is hexadecimal) is by ingesting a bunch of shp files, then storing them in an azure db.  Currently, the only way to read this blob is one manual click at a time down a huge hierarchy of subsets.

I went to

https://hexed.it/?hl=en

and pasted the code and it translated (binary/text) until line 000064A0

Even when it was translated, it just turned to random numbers...

I also asked for help on reddit.
reddit.com/r/codes/comments/421xek/can_somebody_help_me_decode_this_blob/

Here's the file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/om7xjuoztafm17e/Blob.txt?dl=0

The end goal is to build a python program to read this blob.  Once I understand how to translate it, I can take it from there!

Comment: Determining how the geometry is being stored in your BLOBs will help you out greatly. It doesn't look like [WKB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary), nor it is an entire shapefile. You say you are 'ingesting a bunch of files, then storing them in an azure db.' How is the BLOB generated in the first place?

Comment: There are an infinite number of potential formats.  You have this tagged with "esri-geodatabase" -- Is the data stored in an enterprise geodatabase?  If so, what storage format was used?  The database natively supports two formats which don't need to be decoded.  One of these is certainly the format which *should* be used, which would obviate the need to decode an only partially documented SDEBINARY.

Comment: @EvilGenius like this?

POINT(-85.16601269797088,38.295447785748429)

sorry, I am new to actually being a user of stack exchange :P  

a user uploads a zipped file with a bunch of files (.shp and .dbf) then the server reads them in, normalizes it into the db.  For saving space, it runs a binary compression algorythm at some point before it hits our db :)

Is that specific enough?

Comment: it's not an esri database, it's a very geo focused db structured

I will retag it :)

Thanks!

Comment: @user2804240, any chance this blob is from an ESRI Annotation Feature Class table (layer)? ESRI stores a proprietary blob format in their annotation layers. Otherwise ..is it the geometry field, itself? Can you cast it as follows in a DB Query: `SELECT STAsText(blob_field) AS wkt FROM blob_table;` ??

Comment: @elrobis I will try first thing tomorrow morning when im in the db!!!

Thanks for the idea! :)

Comment: @elrobis 
this isn;t working.  I am using sql server management studio 2012
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'STAsText' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a user uploads a zipped file with a bunch of files (.shp and .dbf)

It sounds like you're looking for a shapefile technical document. ESRI has one published at this link:

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/whitepapers/view/productid/21/metaid/279

There are a lot of open source shapefile tools, like [Pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) so you don't need to create your own.

edit: Reading blobs out of a database should be pretty easy with [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) - do a query and then write to a binary filehandle with `f = open('users_zipfile.zip', 'wb')`

Comment: it's not a shp file....it's a blob

the blob is posted on reddit if you want to read it
https://www.reddit.com/r/codes/comments/421xek/can_somebody_help_me_decode_this_blob/

the user uploads, but the application server translates the uploads to blobs

Comment: A blob is just an arbitrary field to hold binary data. (**B**inary **L**arge **Ob**ject) You converted the blob to a hex string in the reddit post. If you were to write the binary from the blob to a file on disk and give it a `.shp` extension, you would probably end up with a shapefile. -edit- it looks like the user is uploading zips, so try unzipping the binary data.

Comment: so I am dealing with a hex string? Not a blob? this hex string is EXACTLY what comes out of the db! Sorry for being unclear by saying help me read this blob.

how do i turn a hex string into a .shp file?
Sorry I am so amateur at this! Your help is really appreciated! :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure, but you should be able to "describe" a table and get the data type. If you see a VARCHAR (or similar) data type then you are dealing with hex strings. If you see BLOB then it is raw binary, which was converted to hex for you when you exported it, since that is the most common way to view raw binary data. In SQL, the command is normally `desc tablename`

Comment: it shows varbinary(max),null)...

but if i copy and paste what i see in sql server management studio, it's that hex string

Comment: there's also a field called "CompressionType" most equal 1 it's got an "uncompressedSize" and "CompressedSize" a "Count", a "DataHash". a "SpatialHash"

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9gmcx0xxktq8i2/ExampleOfBlob.xlsx?dl=0
this is an example of a row... the 3rd column is the terd that needs translating :)

Thanks! :)

Comment: I also found out that in sql server studio, it shows it as a hexadecimal string,.. in python, it converts it to a byte array, and I can actually turn it into a string of numbers.... I honed in a a list of values it could be, but now I am trying to match indexes with what the character could mean

Comment: The python byte array is what you need, just print that to a binary filehandle and you should end up with a zip or a shapefile, hopefully!

Comment: when I tried this, it prints a blank file...

TEXT = Query4.fcd
f = open("C:/Users/scj01/Desktop/Notebook/Output2.txt", 'wb')
f.write(TEXT.values)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with byte arrays, but you may need to loop through the byte array, print each iteration, then close the file.